# Fitting transformed functions with OLS

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, statsmodels

I want to fit a function with statsmodels.ols like this:

```
y ~ a*x_1**b+x_2**c
```

if I understand it right, I can transform that to

```
np.log(y) ~ np.log(x_1) + np.log(x_2)
```

The problem is, that my residuals are also transformed then. Hence, I get a different result as compared to fitting the untransformed function (which is not possible in statsmodels, right?)

Is there a way to transform the residuals back for the fit to get a correct least square fit?

Or is ther another python package that gives a similarly nice summary of the results?

Thanks in advance

Gor